# termios default for standard terminal session

Tags: c, terminal, debian, termios

I would like to create a new pty session in Linux, like as gnome-terminal xterm and others do. Half of my task is working, I created a pty session with openpty, fork()-ed a process, child uses the slave FD, and the remaining process terminal attach to a network socket.

Through the network I can connect to "remote terminal", but it's not working correctly. There's no echo, and characters aren't sent after the enter is pressed (so I can't navigate in nano, mc, etc).

The termios struct's set up with `cfmakeraw(struct termios)`.

**The Question:** what is the default termios settings in a default session like in gnome-terminal and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `NULL` as the `struct termios *` argument to `openpty()` (or `forkpty()`, which you should look into!), and the resulting defaults should be reasonable for an interactive terminal.

Comment: the real problem was:
the network socket  buffered the data until line end character, the ech is also worked but echoed only after line sended.  But this is the most simplest way to setup a terminal, thank you :)

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, which I would like to know -- what is the actual default used by gnome-terminal etc. and how is it determined? Also, if I pass `NULL`, how does it determine what settings to use?

Comment: @tom Passing the `struct termios *` parameter as `NULL` uses default values set by the kernel when the terminal is created. The relevant code in glibc is literally just [`if (termp) tcsetattr(slave, TCSAFLUSH, termp);`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/login/openpty.c#L127).

Comment: Okay thanks--I found [sys/ttydefaults.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/+/master/sysroot/usr/include/sys/ttydefaults.h), is that how the defaults get compiled into the kernel? I'm still wondering about `gnome-terminal` and other terminal apps, do they actually pass `NULL` for this argument or do they set their own settings?

Answer (score 0):

If your standard input, standard output or standard error is going to your terminal and is sane, you could copy the settings from your terminal to your pty using [`tcgetattr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcgetattr.html) and [`tcsetattr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcsetattr.html).

```
struct termios ttyset;

if (tcgetattr(FILE_STDERR, &ttyset) != 0)
    ...handle error - maybe try stdout or stdin...
if (tcsetattr(pty_fd, TCSANOW, &ttyset) != 0)
    ...handle error...
```

Basically, this assumes you have a good set of terminal settings to start with and copies the setting from `FILE_STDERR` to `pty_fd` (which is assumed to be a file descriptor for the slave side of your pseudo-tty).

Of course, you could capture the settings a considerable time before you use them to initialize the pseudo-tty, even though they are shown as adjacent operations in the code fragment above.

Comment: It's also a good solution, copy setting of a working therminal:  
struct termios def;  
memset(&def,0,sizeof(termios));  
tcgetattr(2, &def);  
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)  
std::cout <<  *(((unsigned int*)&def)+i) << "\n";  
  
vales:  
def.c_iflag= 27906;  
def.c_oflag= 5;  
def.c_cflag= 1215;            
def.c_lflag = 35387;  
  
thanks for help:)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this on your local machine is by opening a fresh terminal and running the following code:

```
static struct termios tty;
tcgetattr(0, &tty);
printf("0x%x\n", tty.c_iflag);
printf("0x%x\n", tty.c_oflag);
printf("0x%x\n", tty.c_cflag);
printf("0x%x\n", tty.c_lflag);
```

Which on OSX at time of writing gave me:

```
0x6b02
0x3
0x4b00
0x200005cb
```

When I use these values to construct or repair a terminal it works great, e.g.

```
void reset_term()
{
  static struct termios Otty, Ntty;
  tcgetattr(0, &Otty);
  Ntty = Otty;
  Ntty.c_iflag = 0x6b02;
  Ntty.c_oflag = 0x3;
  Ntty.c_cflag = 0x4b00;
  Ntty.c_lflag = 0x200005cb;

  tcsetattr(0, TCSAFLUSH, &Ntty);
}
```